# Почему — целовальники?

Tags: этимология

До революции была такая административная должность — целовальник. Но почему она так называлась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо руки на конституции целовал крест - клятва служить честно.

Comment: Почему "вместо"? Никакой конституции тогда не было.

Comment: Потому что сейчас есть конституция, а крест никто(почти) не целует. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Это не совсем должность... Скажем так: на Руси в XIV-XVII веках это были избираемые лица для выполнения различных функций в уездах и посадах, которые по избрании, иногда - при выполнении обязанностей, целовали крест.
При этом конкретной должности (особенно на раннем этапе) они не занимали. Или могли не занимать.